# Delete rows method in commitEditingStyle

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'd like to implement a "swipe to delete" option to a tableview. I added the "commitEditingStyle" method and it triggers the swipe and a red box with "delete" shows, but I can't work out what should be inside that method. Any help?
Here's the code:

```
#import "NotificationTableView.h"
#import "NotificationTableViewCell.h"

@interface NotificationTableView () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary* heights;

@end

@implementation NotificationTableView

-(void)awakeFromNib{

UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NotificationTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"NotificationTableViewCell"];
[self registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"NotificationTableViewCellSize"];

self.dataSource = self;
self.delegate = self;
self.estimatedRowHeight = 86;

self.rowHeight =
//    (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) ? UITableViewAutomaticDimension :
86;

self.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
_heights = [NSMutableDictionary new];

}

-(void)setNotifications:(NSArray *)notifications{
_notifications = notifications;
[self reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView endUpdates];
    [self reloadData];
}
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
return self.notifications.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NotificationTableViewCell* cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NotificationTableViewCell"];
[cell configureCellWithNotification:self.notifications[indexPath.row]];
return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
Notification* not = self.notifications[indexPath.row];
[self.notificationDelegate notificationTapped:not];
}

@end
```

Comment: what is notification ? do u get any errors ? what is the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not call `reloadData` in addition to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`. Just do one.
2. You first need to update the data model used by your data source. In this case you need to remove the corresponding row from the `self.notifications` array. This means that you need a mutable array.
3. You don't need the calls to `beginUpdate`/`endUpdate` since you are only making a single call to modify the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-        (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
      commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
       forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            //Get the notification here
            Notification* not = self.notifications[indexPath.row];

            //Remove item in array
            [self.notifications removeObjectIdenticalTo:not];

            // Also remove that row from the table view with an animation
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


        }
```

Comment: This code has two serious flaws. 1) This code will crash if the array contains a given notification more than once. 2) `self.notifications` is an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: This code removes a row, but not from persistent storage. Once I reload the view, the notification I've removed is visible again. Any idea how to delete it completely?

Comment: @toobiz The code doesn't specify how the data source is handled? How are you storing your notifications?

Comment: @Mochi Notification is an ApiObject. It's stored in the server so it reloads when I refresh the view.